# RedCarpet string missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, markdown, redcarpet

I have a Rails app which includes Redcarpets to process markdown. However, when I write  in my article body, it converts nothing. I want to render it to canvas as a string.
My code is

```
renderer = Redcarpet::Render::HTML.new(hard_wrap: true, filter_html: true)
extensions = {fenced_code_blocks: true, autolink: true, no_intraemphasis: true}
redcarpet = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(renderer, extensions)
self.rendered_body = redcarpet.render self.body
```

Body:

```
"##This is a test\r\n<canvas>\r\n* list-1\r\n* list-2"
```

RenderedBody:

```
"<h2>This is a test</h2>\n\n<p>* list-1<br>\n* list-2</p>\n"
```

If I remove the "filter_html" parameter, canvas acts like an HTML5 tag. Canvas is put because of filter_html not existing there.

How can I put html tags as strings?

Comment: What do you mean by "If I remove the "filter_html" parameter...."? What happens when you remove `filter_html`?

Comment: if I write renderer = Redcarpet::Render::HTML.new(hard_wrap: true) <canvas> is back as a html tag.

Comment: Can you give me the HTML output if you do `filter_html: false`?

Comment: yes i did. the result is same.